# Mysql INSERT query of variables in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, insert, double-quotes, single-quotes

I have spent two days trying to figure out why this statement wouldn't insert those data into my database. Been reading through all similar questions here as well and tried with no luck. This is the statement:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO removal_shipment_detail (request_date, order_id, shipment_date, product, product_name, delivered, quantity, local, tracking, update) VALUES ('".$request_date."','".$order_id."','".$shipment_date."','".$product."','".$product_name."','".$delivered."','".$quantity."','".$local."','".$tracking."','".$update."')";
```

Where quantity is a INT here. I've exchanged single quote with double quote back and force combined with the concatenation added and deleted as well, but none of those combinations would work.

Thanks, please advice!

Comment: Provide you db table schema.

Comment: It may be your data is crossing available limit of data types or data mismatched.
Check datatype and character length

Answer (score 3):

`update` is a MySQL reserved word, so you can't use this word as your column name like that.

Here's the reference:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Escape your columns using backticks, like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO removal_shipment_detail (`request_date`, `order_id`, `shipment_date`, `product`, `product_name`, `delivered`, `quantity`, `local`, `tracking`, `update`) VALUES ('".$request_date."','".$order_id."','".$shipment_date."','".$product."','".$product_name."','".$delivered."','".$quantity."','".$local."','".$tracking."','".$update."')";
```

---

**Sidenote:** Learn about [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) because right now your query is susceptible to SQL injection. Also see [how you can prevent SQL injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Thank you! Yeah I am still a noob and there are a lot for me to learn. Thanks for your tip I will try and then back with an update. Thanks for your supported info as well! :D

Comment: Sorry, but this seem not to work either :( I will read through your material and see what to add

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQLi you can check your SQL errors with following methods:

**Object oriented style**

```
if (!$mysqli->query("QUERY_HERE")) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}
```

**Procedural style**

```
if (!mysqli_query($con, "QUERY_HERE")) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
}
```

More informations can be found in [PHP: mysqli:$error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Also I dont like connecting string with `.` when it's not necessary (it' always harder to read). Your syntax can be as follows:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO removal_shipment_detail (`request_date`, `order_id`, `shipment_date`, `product`, `product_name`, `delivered`, `quantity`, `local`, `tracking`, `update`) VALUES ('$request_date','$order_id','$shipment_date','$product','$product_name','$delivered','$quantity','$local','$tracking','$update')";
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for your prompt reply! Let me check on that and update...

Comment: Hi! I copied your code into my PHP and the first one didn't print out anything and the second one only says "Errormessage:" on the webpage. Does it mean it has no error?? Thanks!

Comment: Show me your way how you use mysqli :)

Comment: if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
}

Comment: Is this the right way :D?

Comment: It depends on how is it done in your code. Post something more of code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

try to use intval

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO removal_shipment_detail 
    (request_date, order_id, shipment_date, product, product_name, delivered, quantity, local, tracking, update) 
VALUES
    ('".$request_date."','".$order_id."','".$shipment_date."','".$product."','".$product_name."','".$delivered."',".intval ($quantity).",'".$local."','".$tracking."','".$update."')";
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, if quantity is an INT, then it need not be surrounded with quotes.

Secondly, avoid using reserved words such as "update" for your field names. It may confuse the database engine.

Rajdeep Paul's answer is also good but he failed to talk about the quantity field which has the INT data type.

Try this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO removal_shipment_detail (request_date, order_id, shipment_date, product, product_name, delivered, quantity, local, tracking, update1) VALUES ('".$request_date."','".$order_id."','".$shipment_date."','".$product."','".$product_name."','".$delivered."',".$quantity.",'".$local."','".$tracking."','".$update."')";
```

Notice that the field name "update" has been changed to "update1" to avoid confusing of the sql interpreter and also the quotes surrounding the quantity value have been removed.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Let me try...

Comment: Thank you Shola! I tried but still the data doesn't show in my database. That's so weird... The connection is good without a problem. I'm debugging it by adding the data one by one.